# ORACLE - Substring

Tags: sql, oracle

I found a problem in ORACLE-CERTIFICATE about substring (I guess) that I don't have any idea how to do that. Does anyone understand this??

Create table Bonus and do DML insert to Bonus table for the following script:
Hint: you should be able to ran this script against your table without any error and generate the output "Here is the result".

```
select (substr(
          substr(
            substr(
              l.object,
              instr(l.object,',')+1
            ),
            instr(
              substr(
                l.object,
                instr(l.object,',')+1
              ),
              ','
            )+1
          ),
          instr(
            substr(
              substr(l.object,instr(l.object,',')+1),
              instr(
                substr(
                  l.object,
                  instr(l.object,',')+1
                ),
                ','
              )+1
            ),
            ','
          )+1
        )
      ) ref
from  Bonus l
where l.l_index = 't234'
```

Here is the output:

```
REF                                                         
------------------------------------------------------------
Here is the result
```

Comment: Not really clear what your question is.  The task appears to be to write two SQL statements: (1) a statement to create the table BONUS, and (2) a statement to insert a row into that table, such that the given query will produce the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is looking for the remainder of the string that follows the 3rd comma:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Bonus ( l_index, object ) AS
SELECT 't234', ',,,Here is the result' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
select (substr(
          substr(
            substr(
              l.object,
              instr(l.object,',')+1
            ),
            instr(
              substr(
                l.object,
                instr(l.object,',')+1
              ),
              ','
            )+1
          ),
          instr(
            substr(
              substr(
                l.object,
                instr(l.object,',')+1
              ),
              instr(
                substr(
                  l.object,
                  instr(l.object,',')+1
                ),
                ','
              )+1
            ),
            ','
          )+1
        )
      ) ref
from  Bonus l
where l.l_index = 't234'
```

**Output**:

```
REF                 
---------------------
Here is the result
```

A simpler version of this query would be:

```
SELECT SUBSTR( object, INSTR( object, ',', 1, 3 ) + 1 ) AS ref
FROM   Bonus
WHERE  l_index = 't234';
```